# Favicon not loading until cookies are accepted?

Tags: cookies, favicon

I'm seeing a weird issue where my site's favicon is not loaded until I accept cookies on a cookie plugin.  I wrote the plugin and as far as I know there is no tie of a favicon to cookies and the plugin doesn't explicitly block anything by default. I don't think the favicons are tied to a cookie anyways. Anyone seen this type of behavior before and know how to allow the favicon to load.

[Plugin Github](https://github.com/TortoiseAndHareSoftware/cookie-dash)

Comment: How was the favicon added? Using WordPress? Or by adding a favicon.ico file? Something else?

Comment: have you checked your browsers dev tools for errors? How are you loading the favicon?

Comment: No errors or messages.  The favicon loads fine after I accept or deny cookies and refresh the page, just not before.

Comment: I am using native WordPress favicon loads.  I uploaded the favicon through the customizer and I've also put a link to the file in the HTML for the page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.  In my plugin I was calling an `echo` statement from a `WP_Head` function.  This was causing the `<head>` tag to be immediately closed and rendered in the body.  Any remaining code for the `WP_Head` was being output in the body, including the favicon `<link>` tags.